# pset2 Python Problem3-UsingBisectionSearch.py

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python, and I have lots of problems working out indentation, anyway I need someone to help me understand why my code not working...( The if condition is not recognizing the value from the inner while loop )

```
balance = 1000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate /12
episilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
Low = balance / 12
High = (balance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate )**12) / 12.0 
ans = (Low + High) / 2.0
newbalance = balance
monthlyPayment = ans

while newbalance > 0:
    newbalance = balance
    month = 0

    while month < 12:
        print('low = ' + str(Low) + ' high = ' + str(High) + ' ans = ' + str(ans))
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        newbalance += interest
        month += 1
        print month 


    if(newbalance > 0):
        Low = ans               
    else:
        High = ans

    ans = (Low + High) / 2.0

print 'Lowest payment: ' + str(ans)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be deducting `ans` not `monthlyPayment`, setting `monthlyPayment = ans` outside the loop does not mean `monthlyPayment` will be updated when you set `ans = (Low + High) / 2.0` inside the while loop each time, you are creating a new object each time:

```
while abs(newbalance) > 0.001: # check if we are withing +- .001 of clearing balance
    newbalance = balance
    month = 0
    for month in range(12): # loop over 12 month range
        print('low = ' + str(Low) + ' high = ' + str(High) + ' ans = ' + str(ans))
        newbalance -= ans # deduct ans not the the original value set outside the while
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        newbalance += interest
        print month    
    if newbalance > 0:
        Low = ans
    else:
        High = ans    
    ans = (Low + High) / 2.0    
print "Lowest Payment: {:.2f}".format(ans) # format to two decimal places
```

Also it is better to use `for month in range(12)`, we know we only want to have 12 iterations so much simpler to use range.

Even if you were doing a `ans += 2` your `monthlyPayment` would not be updated as ints are immutable so `monthlyPayment` would still only point to the original value of `ans`.

```
In [1]: ans = 10    
In [2]: monthlyPayment = ans    
In [3]: id(ans) 
Out[3]: 9912448    
In [4]: id(monthlyPayment) # still the same objects
Out[4]: 9912448    
In [5]: ans += 10 # creates new object
In [6]: ans
Out[6]: 20    
In [7]: monthlyPayment # still has original value
Out[7]: 10  
In [8]: id(monthlyPayment)  # same id as original ans
Out[8]: 9912448     
In [9]: id(ans)  # new id because it is a new object
Out[9]: 9912208
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic! now one more question if I wanted to continued with the while loop. why then my code is still wrong ( after changing newbalance -= ans)...  to be more clear, Why my code will only run one time the inner while loop. if after the while loop I declare (if(newbalance > 0)) but this declaration, is not being reconsidered by python.

Comment: because consider - 5000, that is < 0 but not the correct answer. You must find a value that is +- <= your epsilon. That is where `abs()` somes invery handy

Comment: ok, I see that ... but check the results of my code ...(I think this is where I get confused ..)  
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711
low = 83 high = 101.615923742 ans = 92.3079618711

Lowest payment: 87.6539809355

Comment: If you `print newbalance`  you will see that it is  `-15.953093` so that is less than 0 so the while loop stops. The abs check is essential it makes -15 into 15

Comment: In your code after changing to `-= ans` use `while abs(newbalance) > 0.001` and then look at what the balance is when the function is over

Comment: It does indeed read the if but your outer while loop breaks as -15 is < 0

Comment: Thank you! Padraic... You are absolutely right ...> really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez, no prob. enjoy MITx.