# Find lowest monthly debt using bisection search in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the minimum payment to pay off a loan using the following:

```
 initialBalance = 320000
 annualInterestRate = 0.2
 monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
 lo = initialBalance/12.0
 hi = ((initialBalance*(1+(annualInterestRate/12))**12)/12.0)
 epsilon = 0.01
 payment = (lo+hi)/2.0

while abs((payment*12) - initialBalance) >=epsilon:
     balance = initialBalance-payment
     balance += balance*(annualInterestRate/12)
     for i in range(1,12):  
         balance -= payment
         balance += balance*(annualInterestRate/12) 
     if balance > 0:
        lo = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2
    else: 
        hi = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2
print'Lowest payment: ', str(round(payment,2))
```

When I try to run this the program enters in an infinite loop and I don't understand why this is happening. Could anyone help me out here? I have looked at all other similar posts and still don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: `abs` converts any value into a `+tive` one.... I don't think `(payment*12)` is going to be so close `delta < 0.01` to `initialBalance` in near future. So... this is your infinite loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088495/pset2-python-problem3-usingbisectionsearch-py/28088634#28088634

Answer (score 0):

It might be best if you try to find it on your own using the code below, since it looks very hard to figure out what exactly you are trying to do in your code (tip: use comments to make it easy for you, and others to understand your code)

```
import time

# ----------------------------------------------------
# here you can have the rest of your code, variable declaration etc.
# ----------------------------------------------------

while abs((payment*12) - initialBalance) >=epsilon:
    balance = initialBalance-payment
    balance += balance*monthlyInterestRate

    for i in range(1,12):
        balance -= payment
        balance += balance*monthlyInterestRate

    if balance > 0:
        lo = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2

    else:
        hi = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2

    # You can modify the code below to track other variables if you feel like it.
    print '\n--------'
    print 'balance %s' % balance 
    print 'payment %s' % payment
    # Inserts a small delay (in seconds) between prints
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

You can experiment and see which variables get unexpected values and track them down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop until the abs of the updated balance is <= your epsilon

```
initialBalance = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12
lo = initialBalance / 12.0
hi = ((initialBalance * (1 + (annualInterestRate / 12)) ** 12) / 12.0)
epsilon = 0.01
payment = (lo + hi) / 2.0
new_balance = initialBalance
# you want the abs of new_balance to be <= epsilon
while abs(new_balance) >= epsilon:
    # reset new_balance each time
    new_balance = initialBalance
    # loop for twelve months
    for i in range(1, 13):
        new_balance -= payment
        new_balance += monthlyInterestRate * new_balance
    # change low to high and vice versa based on whether we took too much or too little
    if new_balance > 0:
        lo = payment
    else:
        hi = payment
    # recalculate payment based on new high and low
    payment = (lo + hi) / 2


print('Lowest payment: ', str(round(payment, 2)))
```

Using your own code you need to check `abs(balance) >=epsilon` setting `balance = initialBalance` outside the loop:

```
balance = initialBalance
while abs(balance) >=epsilon:
     balance = initialBalance-payment
     balance += balance* monthlyInterestRate
     for i in range(1,12):
         balance -= payment
         balance += balance*(annualInterestRate/12)
     if balance > 0:
        lo = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2
     else:
        hi = payment
        payment =(lo+hi)/2
print('Lowest payment: ', str(round(payment,2)))
```

Using `while abs((payment*12) - initialBalance) >=epsilon:` you are comparing to the initialBalance **not** including any interest so while the payment calculated is correct your loop never ends.